# Adding parameters to Binance GET url gives signature error

Tags: php, curl, binance

Getting `-1022 Signature for this request is not valid.` when I add a parameter to any GET url even though I'm following the correct placement via their [developer faq](https://dev.binance.vision/t/faq-signature-for-this-request-is-not-valid/176) which states to put the parameter first and to `have timestamp and signature (in this order) as the last parameters`. I am having no trouble getting results from urls that don't require any additional parameters besides timestamp/signature.

```
$timestamp = 'timestamp='.time()*1000;
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', $timestamp, $secret);
$url = 'https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/accountSnapshot?type=SPOT&'.$timestamp.'&signature='.$signature;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-MBX-APIKEY:'.$key));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($result);
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

```
$timestamp = 'type=SPOT&timestamp='.time()*1000;
$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', $timestamp, $secret);
$url = 'https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/accountSnapshot?'.$timestamp.'&signature='.$signature;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an additional parameter to the query you need also to insert it into the signature.

So you need to put inside signature the entire query string

```
type=SPOT&'.$timestamp
```